# SQL server 2012 throw in Catch block

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
BEGIN CATCH

      SELECT  ERROR_NUMBER() AS [Error Number],
      ERROR_MESSAGE() AS [ErrorMessage];  

      IF ERROR_NUMBER() IN (  1204, -- SqlOutOfLocks
                              1205, -- SqlDeadlockVictim
                              1222, -- SqlLockRequestTimeout
                              3960,  -- Snapshot Conflict
                              3930  --The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file
                              )
      BEGIN
            SET @RetryCount = @RetryCount + 1  

            WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'  --let the blocking transaction finish
      END 
      ELSE    
      BEGIN
            -- If we don't have a handler for current error
            -- then we throw an exception and abort the loop
            THROW;
    END
END CATCH
```

I am using above code in my procedure, Throw statement show red line in management studio. I am able to deploy the procedure successfully. Do we need to have a statement before throw or can we just put semicolon before throw.

;Throw

Comment: If you can deploy the proc and execute it, just ignore the red lines. you can use THROW without any message or code. refer to sql server document

Comment: The error - if you want to call it like that - results from the fact, that THROW expects a ; at the End of the preceding line. However, changing the line to ;THROW; should do the trick...